# Recursion maintaining ancestors/parents nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a very deep nested category structure and I am given a **category object** that can exist at any depth.  I need to be able to iterate through all category nodes until I find the requested category, plus be able to capture its parent categories all the way through.

Data Structure

```
[
{
    CategoryName: 'Antiques'
},
{
    CategoryName: 'Art',
    children: [
        {
            CategoryName: 'Digital',
            children: [
                {
                    CategoryName: 'Nesting..'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            CategoryName: 'Print'
        }
    ]
},
{
    CategoryName: 'Baby',
    children: [
        {
            CategoryName: 'Toys'
        },
        {
            CategoryName: 'Safety',
            children: [
                {
                    CategoryName: 'Gates'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    CategoryName: 'Books'
}
```

]

Code currently in place

```
function findCategoryParent (categories, category, result) {
    // Iterate through our categories...initially passes in the root categories
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {

        // Check if our current category is the one we are looking for
        if(categories[i] != category){
            if(!categories[i].children)
                continue;

            // We want to store each ancestor in this result array
            var result = result || [];
            result.push(categories[i]);
            // Since we want to return data, we need to return our recursion
            return findCategoryParent(categories[i].children, category, result);
        }else{
            // In case user clicks a parent category and it doesnt hit above logic
            if(categories[i].CategoryLevel == 1)
                result = [];

            // Woohoo...we found it
            result.push(categories[i]);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem

1. If I return my recursive function it will work fine for 'Art' and all of its children..but since it returns, the category Baby never gets hit and therefor would never find *'Gates'* which lives Baby/Safety/Gates
2. If I do not return my recursive function it can only return root level nodes

Would appreciate any recommendations or suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a depth first search to me.

Comment: Write an ES6 generator.

Comment: categories.filter(function(a){return JSON.stringify(a).match('"CategoryName":"Baby"')}); adjust as needed for other cat names

Comment: @dandavis One issue I believe with this one will be that the category name 'Baby' actually can exist multiple places...that is why I have the reference category object and need to know from which that instance came

Comment: you need to make it clearer how far back you want to go from a match.

Comment: @dandavis It needs to be the whole category tree, all the way down to the very instance of the category selected. So if you click 'DDR Memory' it needs to capture [ 'Computer', 'Hardware', 'Memory', 'DDR Memory']...but I only have access to the DDR Memory object...I have to find it and know the path it took to obtain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I believe I found a solution that appears to work for my and not sure why my brain took so long to figure it out...but the solution was of course closure.

Essentially I use closure to keep a scoped recursion and maintain my each iteration that it has traveled through

```
var someobj = {
    find: function (category, tree, path, callback) {
        var self = this;
        for (var i = tree.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            // Closure will allow us to scope our path variable and only what we have traversed
            // in our initial and subsequent closure functions
            (function(){
                // copy but not reference
                var currentPath = path.slice();

                if(tree[i] == category){
                    currentPath.push({name: tree[i].name, id: tree[i].id});
                    var obj = {
                        index: i,
                        category: category,
                        parent: tree,
                        path: currentPath
                    };
                    callback(obj);
                }else{
                    if(tree[i].children){
                        currentPath.push({name: tree[i].name, id: tree[i].id});
                        self.find(category, tree[i].children, currentPath, callback);
                    }
                }

            })(tree[i]);
        }
    },

    /**
     * gets called when user clicks a category to remove
     * @param  {[type]} category [description]
     * @return {[type]}          [description]
     */
    removeCategory: function (category) {
        // starts the quest for our category and its ancestors
        // category is one we want to look for
        // this.list is our root list of categoires,
        // pass in an intial empty array, each closure will add to its own instance
        // callback to finish things off
        this.find(category, this.list, [], function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others that need a way to traverse javascript objects and maintain parent ancestors.

Comment: i was hoping it wouldn't come to a hybrid since that's complicated, but it works. thanks for posting the answer.